# Send emails via mailjet without backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailjet

It would be awesome if I could just send emails via mailjet from the frontend without the need of a backend.

The only implementations on their page are for backend systems.
But shouldn`t it in theory be possible to use mailjet without a backend? Sending emails through mailjet should be nothing more than just some post request, don't they? If so, why is there no JS implementation?

Comment: You can, using [EmailJS.com](http://www.emailjs.com) - it keeps your keys private while allowing you to send pre-built email templates directly from Javascript (disclosure - I'm one of the creators).

Comment: Haha... "Send email directly from Javascript" it seems a little like a parody because that could have been my title. Thanks @Sasha that would solve my problem but in my case I just want to send an email from a contact-form. So the use-case is to small to pay an extra service for it. I'll keep EmialJS in mind for future projects though.

Comment: note that we have a free tier which should be enough for a personal site, but also feel free to reach out to me at (my name at emailjs.com) if you need to bump up the quota. Good luck, anyway :)

Comment: I saw the free plan but there will be a footer attached and that's unfortunately unacceptable for my current project. But thanks anyway @Sasha

Answer (score 5):

*Disclaimer: Mailjet's employee here.*

**As long as you don't expose your credentials to the public**, you can call the Mailjet's APIs using HTTP. The tool's choice is up to you: cURL, [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [Paw](https://paw.cloud/), one of our [language wrappers](https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/#the-libraries), or directly any HTTP call such as XMLHttpRequest for your JavaScript front-end.

You will find many examples in our [documentation](https://dev.mailjet.com).

To learn more about credentials security, I advise you this nice [W3C webappsec credential management ebook](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-credential-management/).

hAPI coding!

Comment: Looks like it could work only in chrome : http://caniuse.com/#search=credential but do you have any example ?

Answer (score 1):

You can but where do you plan to keep your public and private key?